# Display an item search in ajax format from an ecommerce website

Tags: python, ajax, scrapy

I am trying to scrape an ecommerce website (Lazada.sg) and I found a Github code based of on scrapy: https://github.com/talk2div/lazada-scraper. As I'm tinkering how he developed his code, however, I cannot replicate displaying the same URL search in ajax format (correct me if I'm wrong). Here is a sample of the URL for request in scrapy:https://www.lazada.sg/mother-baby/?ajax=true&page=1&spm=a2o42.searchlistcategory.cate_5b6ee3f0Npltyg.

The searches he made are for baby item searches. I am trying to replicate that for Lego items. I would be glad if I can have some help on displaying the URL in the same format as he did for scrapy so I can re-use his code for my own use case. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the links he is querying is part of an enumerated category listed on the page.  You just want to get the search results of a specific keyword so the query will look a little different like this:

```
...
page=1
def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url=f'https://www.lazada.sg/catalog/?_keyori=ss&ajax=true&from=input&isFirstRequest=true&page={self.page}&q=lego&spm=a2o42.searchlistcategory.search.go.d1c332ab2wBQx9')
```

This is the link for the first page.

https://www.lazada.sg/catalog/?_keyori=ss&ajax=true&from=input&isFirstRequest=true&page=1&q=lego&spm=a2o42.searchlistcategory.search.go.d1c332ab2wBQx9

Comment: Hi @Alexander thanks a lot! I have two follow up question if you don't mind.

1. How do I show a item search on a format that you have just shown? Can I do that via inspect source? I am still a beginner on coding and using scrapy TBH.

2. When I run the code I found in github, it is throwing me a Forbidden by robots.txt logs. Does that mean I can't legally scrape it without getting a lawsuit when caught? However, on the other URL that he initially have, it does not show any of that issue. I guess that was an old item search and Lazada have put some safeguarding against crawlers?

Comment: Update: I tried setting ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False and it was working as expected, however, I did not run it for that long. Do I need proxies so not to get banned or have problems in the long run? Thanks